# Como pegar um valor via GET e outros via POST ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php

Tenho um link que passa um valor via GET para uma página:

```
pagina.php?id=1
```

Dentro de `pagina.php` eu tenho um formulário que irá fazer um POST para si própria, mas eu pego o valor do `id` com `$_GET['id']` e o formulário com `$_POST` ao ser submetido.

O problema é que ao submeter o formulário também preciso do valor de `id` junto, mas como ele é recebido via `GET`, incluir um `input hidden` com `name="id"` no formulário não iria funcionar porque o `id` não seria recebido via `GET`.

Como poderia contornar isso enviando o `id` junto com o formulário sendo que apenas o `id` teria que ser recebido via `GET`?

Comment: Não entendi sam.. Porque no action do formulário você não inclui `pagina.php?id=1`?

Comment: Desta forma você conseguirá pegá-lo via `$_GET`

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Boa ideia... é só colocar no action rs... é que o action tava vazio.

Comment: rsrs... As vezes o mais simples não enxergamos.

Comment: Até pensei que eu tinha entendido errado.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Sou novo ainda em PHP, às vezes fico meio perdido. Antes eu mexia com ASP e nele eu pego o valor de uma só forma, seja por GET ou POST.

Comment: Interessante... Nunca mexi com asp.. No php você também consegue pegar de uma forma só através do $_REQUEST. Mas não é muito aconselhável.

Comment: No primeiro carregamento da página (antes de enviar o formulário) você não passa o ID?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, eu pego o ID que vem na URL.

Comment: Então por que não pode colocar esse ID num input hidden? Não entendi essa parte. Passar no action funciona (pelo menos no PHP), mas parece meio deselegante.

Comment: @bfavaretto É que seu colocar no input hidden o $_GET não vai pegar. Mas colocar no action não tem problema não, é uma página interna de cadastros.

Comment: Não vai pegar porque? Só fazer  `<form .... method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?">` Assim apanha tudo pelo post. A questão é que a sua requisição http só tem um tipo, e por isso só é get ou é post, embora consiga obter valores por `$_GET` numa requisição do tipo *post*

Comment: O tio, veja se isso resolve seu `eval`  https://ideone.com/pvX607

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Po, valeu vovô, mas consegui de outro modo, curte só: `$prefix = "dia"; ${$prefix.$x};`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c44feea50dd4bc0c1a5425944e6f66665b627cc6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode tentar fazer assim:

```
<form action="minhaacao.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" method="post">
    <!-- demais inputs -->
</form>
```